# Is it possible for windows task scheduler to communicate with a service?

Tags: c#, windows, service, scheduled-tasks

Usually there are two scenarios to run a scheduled task:

- create a windows service and use some scheduler to trigger a job or
- create an exe and start it by the task scheduler

but have anyone tried yet to create a windows service without an integrated scheduler but receive events from the windows task scheduler?

Is it possible for a windows service and the windows task scheduler to communicate so that the windows service can receive events from the task scheduler telling it when it's time to start working?

I'm not thinking of starting and stopping the service. I want it to be running normally and awaiting events from the task scheduler. As soon as one arrives it should start to do its job.

Comment: There's multiple ways to achieve this result. The trick is to remember that you can execute anything from the task scheduler. From there, you can for instance write to a file that is monitored by the service, or execute a custom executable that will use inter-process communication (named pipes) to give orders to the service

Comment: @KooKiz inter-process communication via a custom exe is not exactly what I had imagined but I actaully like it. I'll try this. Now I only have to find out how to broadcast a message to multiple processes becasue there might be more then one service to trigger at the same time and others at different times.

Comment: Broadcasting a message to multiple processes sounds needlessly complicated. Just iterate through them, one at a time. It shouldn't take more than a few hundred microseconds per process anyway